# Strange Linechart hAxis and tooltip position while DataTable seems to be correct

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have an array which is used to create a DataTable in Google Charts.

The array looks like this.

```
[
    ["date", "count"],
    [Mon Sep 22 2014 18:07:03 GMT+0200 (CEST), 4], // First member is actually a Date Object!
    [Tue Sep 23 2014 21:54:10 GMT+0200 (CEST), 7],
    [Thu Sep 25 2014 03:37:30 GMT+0200 (CEST), 9],
    [Fri Sep 26 2014 05:27:30 GMT+0200 (CEST), 10]
]
```

When thrown at the chart machinery like this...:

```
var chartModel = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dateAwareChartModel);
var dateFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({formatType: "short"});
dateFormatter.format(chartModel, 0);
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartContext);
chart.draw(chartModel, {hAxis: {format: "dd MMM yy"}, tooltip: {trigger: "selection"}});
```

...it ends up with this chart:

[image]

At least two things are pretty strange here:

1. Why is 09/23 the starting point? I expected 09/22.
2. The selectable points are at weird positions (not only the visible one in the picture. They're all placed somehow awkwardly shifted). The example at the google charts tutorial shows them right over the hAxis value where these nice vertical orientation lines are.

What do I need to configure here?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1:**

Like kums pointed out, `arrayToDataTable` seems to be the wrong way:

> google.visualization.arrayToDataTable()
>
> This method takes in a 2-dimensional array and converts it to a
>   DataTable.
>
> The column data types are determined automatically by the data
>   submitted. **This method does not support the use of Date or DateTime
>   values**, and also does not support use of the JavaScript literal cell
>   object with f or v values: {v: 3.0, f: 'Three'}. If you need to
>   specify custom cell values, or a formatted value, or Date/DateTime
>   value, use DataTable.addRow()/DataTable.addRows() or
>   DataTable.setValue().

I'm using `addRow` now:

```
var chartModel = new google.visualization.DataTable();
chartModel.addColumn("date", dateAwareChartModel[0][0]);
chartModel.addColumn("number", dateAwareChartModel[0][1]);
for (var i = 1 ; i < dateAwareChartModel.length ; i++) {
    chartModel.addRow(dateAwareChartModel[i]);
}
var opts = {hAxis: {format: "dd MMM yy"}, tooltip: {trigger: "selection"}};
new google.visualization.LineChart(chartContext).draw(chartModel, opts);
```

It could be more elegant, I know. It's just a quick and dirty approach here.

The interesting thing is, that the problems described earlier are still there.

The good news is that the positioning of the selection points isn't strange. It's intended that way. The positioning depends on the time of the day.

The question is now: How can I tell LineChart to ignore time-values and only concentrate on the plane date instead?

**UPDATE 2:**

To be more specific when talking about ignoring time-values:

Imagine any entry like this:

```
[Tue Sep 23 2014 21:54:10 GMT+0200 (CEST), 7]
```

Is it possible to let the line chart display

```
[Tue Sep 23 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), 7]
```

This would automatically lead to correctly placed labels.

At the time I'm achieving this by changing my model explicitly (creating new dates for each day, setting the time to midnight).
I was wondering if there's a less verbose way to let the charts simply ignore the exact time.

Comment: According to [Google Visualization docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google.visualization.arraytodatatable)  **arrayToDataTable** does not support Date/DateTime value. Therefore, the provided date-time is processed incorrectly.

Comment: The docs are out of date - the arrayToDataTable function supports all data types now (otherwise, your chart would not have drawn at all); you do not need to change the DataTable construction if you don't want to.  The reason the labels are offset is because the "datetime" data type is a continuous type, so the axis tick marks will not necessarily align with the data points.  In your case, I suspect you are getting tick marks every 12 hours, but your axis formatting is obscuring the hours.  When you say you would like the chart to ignore time values, what would you like to happen?